# How to forward URL query in nginx dynamically and strip extra params

Tags: nginx

I have a couple thousand URL's that look like the following:

```
https://www.example.com/supplier-shop/u-23452345/s-p/
https://www.example.com/supplier-shop/u-1714128138
https://www.example.com/supplier-shop/u-436877957/s-p
https://www.example.com/supplier-shop/u-32452345
https://www.example.com/supplier-shop/u-2345245664
https://www.example.com/supplier-shop/u-23452345/
```

This is from my legacy website but our new URL structure looks like the following:

`www.example.com/seller/xxxxxxxx`

I know how to rewrite single URL's but how would I do a catch all case for all of my `id`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your answer:

```
location ~ ^/supplier-shop/(?<id>(.*)) {
    rewrite ^ http://$server_name/seller/$id permanent;
}
```

Works as well for `n` level directories as well. Example:

```
> GET /supplier-shop/asdasd/asdasd HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Thu, 28 Jun 2018 00:10:02 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 194
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.example.com/seller/asdasd/asdasd
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess with a rewrite like the following you may achieve what you are looking for

```
location ~ ^/supplier-shop/(.+) {
    rewrite ^ http://$server_name/seller/$1 permanent;
}
```

Guess the **http://$server_name** can be omitted, but honestly I don't have an nginx to try what I'm suggesting right now, so better try it and see the results.

Basically the it makes is replacing the "supplier-shop" with the "seller" and taking all that follows and putting into place.

If it's not what you are trying to achieve, let us know

Comment: All this is doing is stripping everything after `/supplier-shop/` and replacing it with `seller`